# Unable to Install Ubuntu in my Windows 7 system

Tags: system-installation

I was trying to install Ubuntu in my system. I tried to install it from DVD. But what happens is, inbetween system is asking to remove the DVD from the drive and when I does that it sprestarted without installing Ubuntu. Can somebody help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing Ubuntu off of a USB drive rather than a DVD.
[Linux Live USB](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/home) is a pretty easy usb drive creator. Just download the Ubuntu Image (sever or desktop from their site).

[A helpful write up about Dual booting and partition set up](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-ubuntu.html)